# When i deploy my Net 6 core asp.net mvc project i can see the view folder but i cannot update only those files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, .net-6.0

when i first used visual studio 2022 i created my new application web ASP.NET Core (mvc) and i deployed my webiste and all works great.. after the first deploy i realised that i hade only an .exe on the server side and i could not update some of my views... so the problem was " how to deploy the view and be able to update only one wiew"

Now.. i added in my PROJECT.csproj the following code :

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
**<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
<RazorCompileOnPublish>false</RazorCompileOnPublish>**
```

now, when i deploy i can actually see the folder "Views" and i can copy all my files on the server... till here great!

BUT THE PROBLEM IS :
if i modify one of the view with my visual studio and after i try to replace it in my server side, no modification is showen.. more over.. if i delete the views files on the server side, the website still work.. so it look like the folder views is just ther doing nothig...

**How can i deploy the view and be able to modify them without deploying all the website?**

Thanks